# Edit the contours of faces in images using ML Kit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase-mlkit, face

I was able to build an IOS app using google's ML Kit Face Contour API to identify facial features in images with Firebase ML Kit which was found here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-ios/#0

My next step is to edit the contours of faces such as change the lip colour and make the eyes brighten. Any idea on where I can find reference on how to do this?

My end result is a Selfie Editor app similar to what Facetune app does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid currently MLKit doesn't support the feature to `edit` the contours.